# Menu notification auto-refresh issue

Tags: javascript, php, notifications

This code I use to show menu and its notification, but my problem is that the new message notification does not appear before the page reloads. I want to auto-reload this part to show new message notification.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="initChat(0); return false;">
        <i class="linea linea-basic-message-txt"></i>
        <span><?=$system->translate('Messages')?></span>
        <?=$my_user->NotificationCount('messages')?>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Use something like an AJAX call to run in the background and check for changes.

Comment: i want solution sir, i don't know much about ajax that's why i am here

Comment: That's not what stack is meant for, it is meant to learn things and not to get the copy/paste solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadNotification(){
    $('#notifications li a').load('notification.php',function () {
         $(this).unwrap();
    });
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load
setInterval(function(){
    loadlink() // this will run after every 5 seconds
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Avoid only code answer

Comment: Your codes comments does not explain enough. Is it Ajax ? Why you use it ? Why wait 5seconds etc ... Take a look here  : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer